# Dancer2 IF statements in template

Tags: if-statement, template-toolkit

I'm working on a page that has a dropdown menu that gets populated from a database query. I also have an incoming parameter that, if it's populated, will match one of the options in the dropdown. If that parameter is populated, I want the option in the drowpdown to be selected. My instinct is to do something like the following (where `foo` is an entry in a `FOREACH`):

```
<% IF param -eq foo %>
    <option value="foo" selected="selected">foo</option>
<% ELSE %>
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
<% END %>
```

The problem is that I get an error that `foo` is an unrecognized token.

I can't find any evidence in documentation or examples that I can actually use the `param -eq foo` construct above. The examples I can find of `IF` statements don't use comparative operators. They basically only read a boolean parameter or check that a parameter has a value. But since it doesn't reject the `-eq` token, I've been holding out hope that there's a way to do it and that I just haven't figured out the right syntax or found the documentation yet.

Comment: Which template engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the pertinent documentation:  http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_IF_UNLESS_ELSIF_ELSE

It's not `-eq`, it's `==`. But that being the case, I'm still not sure why `-eq` didn't throw an error.

Comment: I reckon it was parsed as `IF "param" MINUS "eq" foo`, so it blew up expecting a comparison operator where `foo` was found.